# Getting the button and input fields in one line

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a form where I'm pulling some data from my company DB, but the fields are not aligning in one line. The original code was using a custom image for to delete the fields, but it never sat inline. I tried to create a new version where 4 fields would be inline with the delete button. This is what I have so far.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import "./styles.css";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1)
  }
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <div>This Grid is always auto-layout.</div>
      <Grid container spacing={10}>
        {/* {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].map(() => ( */}
        <Grid item form="maincomponent" xs>
          <TextField required label="true" type="number" />
          <TextField required label="true" type="number" />
          <TextField required label="true" type="number" />
          <TextField required label="true" type="number" />
          <IconButton
            color="secondary"
            className={classes.button}
            aria-label="delete"
          >
            <DeleteIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Grid>
        {/* ))} */}
      </Grid>
      {/* <br />
      <br />
      <Grid container spacing={24}>
        {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].map(() => (
          <Grid item xs={4} sm={3} md>
            <TextField required label="4/3/true" type="number" />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid> */}
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I picked this from a tutorial, and modified it as per my needs. So far, I have tried to manipulate the original code (can't post here since its company code) using the following grid props: alignContent, alignItems, justify and justifyContent. When I was not able to achieve the effect that I wanted, I tried manipulating sm and xs in the Field Tag from material-ui. I don't really understand these very well (first job) and would appreciate any direction. I've read the API, and unfortunately it gives the same description for the double-alphabet attribute [[lg,md,sm,xl,xs]](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/).

Appreciate any help!

I have tried working the code on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-ritchie-3dk0p).

Comment: The sandbox doesn't seem to exist

Comment: Codesandbox link gives a 404

Comment: I was worried it would do that. Copy-pasting the code in the sandbox will get it to run. DependenciIe will have to be manually added. Sorry! s'll try and get it up and running meanwhile, and will post here as soon as I figure it out.

Edit: okay, it works!

Comment: @foreverAnIntern just wrote you a solution, let me know if that helps ;)

Comment: It sort of did! While I'm still facing alignment issues, I'm at least able to get it all in one line. I imagine I'll have to mess around with the CSS to get it right. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @foreverAnIntern you're welcome friend! Happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the inner Grid tag, you can just give it a class with some flex styling. That will force all children elements to be on the same line.

**Component**

```
  <Grid container spacing={10}>
    {/* {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].map(() => ( */}
    <Grid className="d-flex" item form="maincomponent" xs>
      <TextField required label="true" type="number" />
      <TextField required label="true" type="number" />
      <TextField required label="true" type="number" />
      <TextField required label="true" type="number" />
      <IconButton
        color="secondary"
        className={classes.button}
        aria-label="delete"
      >
        <DeleteIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </Grid>
    {/* ))} */}
  </Grid>
```

**CSS**

```
.d-flex{
   display: flex
}
```

See sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-pine-4kzs7